# Why getting firebase is not defined error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, undefined

Here's the code for the `firebase.js` file where I'm getting this error in spite of strictly adhering to the official documentation of Firebase.

`firebase.js`

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore ,getDocs} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-firestore.js' 
import { collection} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.3/firebase-firestore.js' 
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  // Configuration
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Firebase documentation on initializing Cloud Firestore:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, getDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
    // ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

You can refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-9_1) to get started in your Cloud Firestore application.